# Calling a custom SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This feels like a basic question, but I have tried everything! I'm writing a custom function SQL function to convert integers into dates:

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_to_date (@fin INT)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @fout DATE
    SET @fout = CASE WHEN @fin IN ('','99999999','0','1') THEN NULL
        ELSE CONVERT(DATE,CAST(@fin AS CHAR(8)))
        END
    RETURN @fout
END

SELECT dbo.convert_to_date(DtSurgDischarge) AS DischargeDate
FROM [TR_MASTER.registry].[dbo].[mgh_tumor]
```

I get the following error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure convert_to_date, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

What am I doing wrong?  Feels like it must be obvious.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least you need a `GO` after the `END` statement of the function, if you're attempting to execute both the function create and the `SELECT` in one script - *assuming* you're using SSMS to run the script, that is.

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_to_date (@fin INT)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @fout DATE
    SET @fout = CASE WHEN @fin IN ('','99999999','0','1') THEN NULL
        ELSE CONVERT(DATE,CAST(@fin AS CHAR(8)))
        END
    RETURN @fout
END

GO

SELECT dbo.convert_to_date(DtSurgDischarge) AS DischargeDate
FROM [TR_MASTER.registry].[dbo].[mgh_tumor]
```

Comment: Perfect!  See, I told you this was a basic question!  Now why I couldn't find that in all the googling I did is absolutely beyond me.  Thanks.

Comment: @registrar - no problem, glad to be of assistance.  The GO demarcates the `CREATE FUNCTION` from the `SELECT` - it indicates the end of one batch and the beginning of another.

Comment: @registrar, if you feel like Will's answer solved your problem feel free to accept it by click the checkbox in the top left of his answer

Comment: @Abe Miessler, I have been trying.  StackOverflow apparently doesn't allow accepts until the question (or answer?) has been up for ten minutes.  There's a little countdown timer telling me I can accept in n minutes.